# How would u create this function and perform it inside an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

1. I have an `array`
2. I am trying to create a `function` with `two parameters` that would return a `string` value or expression based on the `condition` such as the year band member joined and left

3.i am trying to run this `function` without any loop and in a newbie manner inside an `array`

```js
const everyMember = ['Mike Portnoy', 'Charlie Dominici', 'John Petrucci', 'John Myung', 'Kelvin Moore', 'Derek Sherinian', 'James Labrie', 'Mike Manzini'];

const calcActiveYear = function(yearJoined,yearLeft){
    if(calcActiveYear === ' '){
         `Member still present since ${year}`;
    }else{
    return yearLeft - yearJoined;
    }
    // return yearLeft - yearJoined;
}

const activeYear = [
    calcActiveYear(everyMember[0]),
    calcActiveYear(everyMember[1]),
    calcActiveYear(everyMember[2]),
    calcActiveYear(everyMember[3]),
    calcActiveYear(everyMember[4]),
    calcActiveYear(everyMember[5]),
    calcActiveYear(everyMember[6]),
    calcActiveYear(everyMember[7]),
]

console.log(activeYear);
```

This is the kind of output i am expecting -

```js
const calcActiveYear = function(yearJoined,yearLeft){
    return yearLeft- yearJoined;
}


const MIkePortnoy = calcActiveYear(1985,2010);
const CharlieDominici = calcActiveYear(1987,1990);
const JohnPetrucci = calcActiveYear();
const JohnMyung = calcActiveYear();
const KelvinMoore = calcActiveYear(1986,1994);
const DerekSherinian = calcActiveYear(1994,1999);
const JamesLabrie = calcActiveYear();
const mikeManzini = calcActiveYear();

console.log(MIkePortnoy,CharlieDominici,JohnPetrucci,JohnMyung, KelvinMoore, DerekSherinian, JamesLabrie)
```

Plz help me out on how would you do it rather than just pointing me out the obvious error here.Thank you!

**note** i am trying to find the limitations of arrays.No objects,loops,prototyping.

Comment: You're setting `calcActiveYear` explicitly as a function; how did you expect it to turn into a string?

Comment: please provide an input and output set clearly. It is not clear to the reader

Comment: In the calcActiveYear definition, it expects two parameters (yearJoined, yearLeft) whereas in the ActiveYear array you are only passing the member name as a single parameter. would you please elaborate on your input and expected output?

Comment: everyMember is a list of string, which contains names. now you pass its members to calcActiveYear, how does that work ? I believe  everyMember must be an array of objects with {yearJoined, yearLeft}, then it would make sense. calcActiveYear needs to take {yearJoined, yearLeft} as input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical technique is to use `Array.prototype.map` -

```js
function calcActiveYear(yearJoined, yearLeft)
{ if (!yearLeft)
    return `Member active since ${yearJoined}`
  else
    return `Active ${yearJoined} - ${yearLeft}`
}

const members =
  [ { name: "Alice", joined: 2000, departed: 2020 }
  , { name: "Bob", joined: 1999, departed: 2010 }
  , { name: "Cindy", joined: 2005, departed: null }
  ]

console.log(members.map(m => calcActiveYear(m.joined, m.departed)))
```

```js
[
  "Active 2000 - 2020",
  "Active 1999 - 2010",
  "Member active since 2005"
]
```

Another effective technique is the `for..of` loop -

```js
for (const m of members)
  console.log(`${m.name}: ${calcActiveYear(m.joined, m.departed)}`)
```

```
Alice: Active 2000 - 2020
Bob: Active 1999 - 2010
Cindy: Member active since 2005
```

Per your comment, you can do this without `Array.prototype.map` or `for` loops -

```js
function calcActiveYear(yearJoined, yearLeft)
{ if (!yearLeft)
    return `Member active since ${yearJoined}`
  else
    return `Active ${yearJoined} - ${yearLeft}`
}

function map(arr, transform, i = 0)
{ if (i >= arr.length)
    return []
  else
    return [transform(arr[i]), ...map(arr, transform, i + 1)]
}

const members =
  [ { name: "Alice", joined: 2000, departed: 2020 }
  , { name: "Bob", joined: 1999, departed: 2010 }
  , { name: "Cindy", joined: 2005, departed: null }
  ]

console.log(map(members, m => calcActiveYear(m.joined, m.departed)))
```

Comment: Thank you for this.I just wanted to know how would any experienced brogrammers do it without any other features such as object,loop or prototyping.Trying to find the limitations of arrays.

Comment: @Nafi I updated the post with a recursion example. Does this answer your question?

Comment: yes.this recursive example certainly answer what i was looking for you.Thank you again thank you.